# Activating a door bell inside apartment after motion sensor outside detects movement

Tags: electrical, lighting, motion-sensor, doorbell

Does anyone know what is the best way to connect a doorbell switch to a 3-way motion sensor switch that currently turns on lights in an entryway?

Comment: Do you want the bell to ring briefly or continuously until turned off? d you want the sensor to continue to run the lights?

Comment: Doorbells typically are running on 24V or less, while your sensor is turning on (I think) the 120V to the lights.  This means you'd need a transformer as well as more wires.

Comment: Do you have an existing doorbell you're attempting to use, or could you replace the whole of the concept with a "motion activated bell", rather than altering an existing system. I'm fairly certain there are whole alarm type systems like this used for monitoring if a small child gets out of bed, leaves their room, or raids the fridge.

Comment: @bib, I only want to briefly ring once indoors.   I really only want this to be the first level of alert as anyone that would get into that hallway would need to have a key, just want to use it for any intrusions in the middle of the night as a first alert.  Also, yes, the lights should be running until the 5-10mins timer on the switch runs out.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk, I don't have a doorbell, this would be more of warning sign to be ring within the apartment to let me know someone is in the hallway.

Comment: @macutan I would try a google search for "Wireless Motion Sensor Alarm and Chime Kit". This is a readily available series/type of product you can buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [120 volt single stroke bell](https://www.edwards-signals.com/files/c-332_&_333_Series_Catalog_Page.pdf)s. These ring once when the circuit is completed.

[image: bell]

This bell would need to be wired in parallel with the lights that the motion sensor controls. Simply add the the bell's hot lead to the black wire that carries the switched hot from the motion detector to the light (both light and bell will be connected to this wire). Then connect the bell''s neutral to the neutral feeding the light (again, both bell and light will be attached to the neutral).

When the motion sensor triggers the lights, it will also trigger the bell to ring once.

```
 Images and links are for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```